# Nexus One's 3.5mm headphone jack accepts standard 3.5mm plug?

Tags: nexus-one, headphone-jack

As you know, the Nexus One comes with a **4**-segment 3.5mm headphone jack, whereas the standard 3.5mm plug has 3 segments.

I visually compared a standard 3-segment 3.5mm plug with the **4**-segment 3.5mm plug that comes with the original Nexus One headset and they seem identical in length.

My only concern is that plugging in a standard 3-segment into this **4**-segment jack will damage the Nexus One.

Better safe than sorry... so instead of empirically plugging in the standard 3-segment plug in the the N1 just to see whether it causes a fatal short or not, I prefer to ask those who are already knowledgeable with this: Is it **safe** to use a standard 3-segment with the N1 headphone jack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phone should be fine.

Android won't route phone calls through headphones though, iPhone can be set to do so and uses the phone's microphone.

An option I use to attach standard headphone to my Galaxy S is a simple Bluetooth headphone adapter (£10 from Amazon), that way I get to use MY headphones and make calls via them, plus you can keep your phone in your pocket when skating into town!

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. What do you mean by "won't route phone calls through headphones"? When I use the original headset that came with the Nexus One, I can hear the audio in the earpieces. Can you explain?  Also, if you can provide a link (or just a brand/model#) to the Bluetooth headphone adapter you mentioned, this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Headphones don't have a mic, so Android cant use it as a Headset, even though the phone has a mic on it...I have this one from Amazon UK http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nexxus-Bluemusic-Stereo-Bluetooth-headset/dp/B0036TGIOO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1302091828&sr=8-2  I use it all the time, especially as I use Music Link headphones that work with my hearing aids - but it works with ANY 3.5mm stereo jack headphones

Comment: @Adrian: what exactly do you mean by "can't use it as a headset"? I have a 4-segment audio plug that comes with my Samsung Spica, and I can use its mic just fine.

Comment: headSETs have 4 segment plugs, ground,left,right and mic  - they WORK. headPHONES dont have a mic and only have 3 segment jacks ground, left, right, and cannot be used for PHONE CALLS, at least on my Galaxy S - so I have to use the BT adapter to use my headPHONES for music and CALLs

Comment: @Adrian I have been able to use 3-segment headphones for phone calls (hearing the call through the phones) since the day I got my Galaxy S.

Comment: @Matthew Do you have a newer model? an i900x? Can you plug headphones in and make a call, I cannot, and nor can many others on the internet...What make/model headphones are you using?

Comment: @Adrian I have an older T959. The headphones are Sennheiser HD205's.

Comment: From what I gather the T959 is a later model, for the US market, in the SGS line. Perhaps Samsung picked up on the Headphone issue - I have a recollection that US accessibly laws requiring headphones to use the mobile phone's mic, for hearing impaired users...I've looked into this previously looking for mobile phones compatible with hearing aids...